# Chinese numbers for book parts?

Tags: numbering, languages

We want to have headings for book parts in Chinese. We already found the `zhnumber` package, which does the job for section numbers. But it somehow fails on parts. It always produces a Chinese zero. I did some debugging and found out that the value of `\thepart` is a roman number that is `I` or `II`. `zhnumber` seems to translate this to zero.

Is there a way to get `zhnumber` working on romance numbers?

Comment: With `\def\thepart{\zhdig{part}}` I see no problem.

Comment: Thanks! We had `\renewcommand{\partname}{第\zhnumber{\thepart}部分}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.